# Как обновить Activity?

Tags: android, activity

У меня есть одно активити,в котором я вызываю фрагменты с помощью NavigationDrawer.

В одном из фрагментов я обновляю пользователю его фото: загружаю фотографию ему в профиль.
Но вот в чём проблема, загрузив фото оно не обновляется в активити.
Не знаю как поступить...

Вот я обновил фотографию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в активити осталась старая фотография...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

main_activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT=2;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 500;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setNameInHead();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        checkName();

        Fragment fragment=new Lobby();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,fragment).commit();
    }

    public void checkName(){
        final FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user.getDisplayName()==null){

            //Получаем вид с файла name_add.xml, который применим для диалогового окна:
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
            View dialog = li.inflate(R.layout.add_displayname, null);

            //Создаем AlertDialog
            AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert);

            //Настраиваем dialog_add.xml для нашего AlertDialog:
            mDialogBuilder.setView(dialog);

            //Настраиваем отображение поля для ввода текста в открытом диалоге:
            final EditText userInput = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dn_et);

            //Настраиваем сообщение в диалоговом окне:
            mDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                            .setDisplayName(userInput.getText().toString())
                                            //.setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
                                            .build();
                                    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Имя добавлено",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profiles").child(user.getUid())
                                            .setValue(new ProfileUserInfo(userInput.getText().toString()));
                                }
                            });

            //Создаем AlertDialog:
            AlertDialog alertDialog = mDialogBuilder.create();

            //и отображаем его:
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setNameInHead();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        setNameInHead();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setNameInHead();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        setNameInHead();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        setNameInHead();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        setNameInHead();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.menu_profile) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    Fragment fragment=new Profile();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,fragment).commit();
                }
            }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
        } else if (id == R.id.menu_lobby) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    Fragment fragment=new Lobby();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,fragment).commit();
                }
            }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
        } else if (id == R.id.menu_add_user) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    Fragment fragment=new AddUser();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,fragment).commit();
                }
            }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
        } else if (id == R.id.menu_sign_out) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BeginSign.class));

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    public void setNameInHead(){
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        if( navigationView != null ){
            LinearLayout mParent = ( LinearLayout ) navigationView.getHeaderView( 0 );
            final TextView headerProfileName=(TextView)mParent.findViewById(R.id.main_nick);
            final CircularImageView photo=(CircularImageView)mParent.findViewById(R.id.main_photo);
            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profiles").child(user.getUid());

            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ProfileUserInfo userInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProfileUserInfo.class);
                    if (userInfo == null) {
                        headerProfileName.setText("");
                    } else {
                        headerProfileName.setText(userInfo.getName());
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getPhotoUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обьявите `final CircularImageView photo;`как перменную класса `MainActivity`  и добавьте 
`getCircularImageView()` метод для `MainActivity`,затем из фрагмента получите ваш `CircularImageView`

```
CircularImageView photo = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getCircularImageView();
```

далее заменить изображение на новое.